# How to calculate the target physical address given the base address and the memory

Tags: 64-bit, hex, offset, memory-address, base-address

So given I have a 64 bit machine. I know that the memory of the address where my program loads is )

```
0x8000:0000 and
```

I need to find the destination memory address such that from 0x8000:0000 , I have at least 512 MB between.

So how do I find out what this destination memory is?

The calculation I did was 8000:0000 + 0x20000000 = result is the destination. But I am not entirely sure if it is correct. So I would need some help in here. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? There are a lot of things you're overlooking here. Virtual address space, paging, segmentation, etc.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I want to find out this memory address into which I can write some patterns out to test. But the thing is I need to find the destination after which I can write these test patterns safely. So I know 512 MB after 0X8000:0000 address is safe. But i need to find the exact address so that I can explicitly use the memory address

Comment: I guess my question is, where are you getting this address (and specifically, this notation)?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I got this address from the system memory map in technical reference manual. This 512 MB is limit set by me for some purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like `0x8000:0000` is typically used to represent a an address in segment:offset notation, when used with a [segmented memory architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation). Is that what you're dealing with here?  If so, 0x8000:0000 = 0x80000. And 0x80000 + 0x20000000 = 0x20080000.